# Custom SAML policy decryption methods

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have custom policy for Azure B2C to work with SAML 2.0 identity provider which responding only with encrypted assertions. Currently identity provider has been deprecated support for AES-CBC and default is currently AES-GCM.

I defined SamlAssertionDecryption key and tried work with default AES-GCM encryption. According trace logs it gave my only "The specified Uri is not supported" error. I forced on the identity provider side to use deprecated AES-CBC encryption and after that B2C started to understand the response.

Anyone know is there somewhere settings which can be used to force B2C use AES-GCM? If AES-GCM is not supported, is there roadmap when it is available? According info I have, identity provider supports older AES-CBC to the end of the year 2021 at least.

Comment: Thanks @Jupek and please follow this document mentioned the support of AES-XXX method. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-and/end-of-support-for-non-secure-cipher-suites-in-microsoft-cloud/ba-p/1596262

Comment: Hmm...I don't understand how I can control cipher suites what Azure AD B2C uses on decryption phase. I don't see relevance for that posted article. Please explain.

Comment: Anyone other advice how to get AES-GCM algorithm support for B2C?

Comment: @Jupek did you solve this problem? I struggle with the same issue.

Comment: I asked this same question via Microsoft Premier support after this post. Product team confirmed that AES-GCM is not supported. These are supported: RSA Public Key Cryptography Standard (PKCS) Version 1.5 algorithm, RSA Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding (OAEP) encryption algorithm, 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm, 192-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm, 128-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I know to make this work is to build (or buy) some sort of proxy implementation which can communicate with B2C some of the supported decryption methods and communicate with identity provider with AES-GCM.

According the product team, regarding roadmap and possible support for AES-GCM there is no plans to implemented that currently to B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same discussion with Microsoft a few months back and their developer working with B2C confirmed that GCM cipher mode is not supported by B2C in saml assertions.

On the other hand the potential security vulnerability related to CBC has not been observed in the wild. On top of that if the saml assertions are properly signed and verified then the risk is even lower.